# Ubuntu installer not showing install options

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, partitioning, system-installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 on my laptop to dual boot with windows 10, but whenever I boot into the usb and start the installer neither of the options to install alongside windows or to just erase it show up and I'm just taken directly to the partition screen. Also, when I try to create a new partition by pressing the "plus" button, the installer freezes.

Comment: Maybe prepare the partitions before running the Ubuntu Installer. You can use `gparted` for that.

Comment: Think I would redownload and try again, seems like something is wrong.  You should get the options.

Comment: I tried redownloading but it didn't make a difference

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Turns out that my laptop's SSD came in RST mode, which ubuntu apparently doesn't support natively, so I had to go set it to AHCI before booting from the usb.